# Cupy - TypeError: Unsupported type <type 'numpy.ndarray'>

Tags: python, numpy, cupy

I want to try `cupy` for image exposure fusion process because we use a lot of `numpy` in algorithms. The following code parts shows the functions and lines that causes errors.

`image_stack` is a list of images that have different exposures. The code for creating `image_stack` is:

```
def load_images(path, mode='color'):
    """
   FUNCTION: load_images
        Call to load images colored or grayscale and stack them. 
     INPUTS:
        path = location of image
        mode = 'grayscale' or 'colored'
    OUTPUTS:
        read data file
    """

    image_stack = []; i = 0
    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        print("Loading... /" + filename + "...as Image_stack["+str(i)+"]")
        if mode == 'color':
            image = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, filename), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        else: #mode == 'gray':
            image = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, filename), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        image_stack.append(cv2.resize(image,(864,576), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA))
        #image_stack.append(image)
        i += 1
    print("\n")
    return image_stack
```

The function below supposed to calculate scalar weight map based on mathematical approach. I directly changed `import numpy as np` to `import cupy as np`. However, I faced an issue from this function.

```
def scalar_weight_map(image_stack, weights=[1,1,1]):

"""
 FUNCTION: scalar_weight_map
    Call to forcefully "AND"-combine all quality measures defined 
 INPUTS:
    image_measures = stack of quality measures computed for image i 
    image_measures[contrast, saturation, exposedness]
    weights = weight for each quality measure : weights[wc, ws, we]
 OUTPUTS:
    scalar_weight_map for particular image
"""

H = np.shape(image_stack[0])[0]; 
W = np.shape(image_stack[0])[1]; 
D = len(image_stack);
Wijk = np.zeros((H,W,D), dtype='float64')
wc = weights[0]
ws = weights[1]
we = weights[2]
print("Computing Weight Maps from Measures using: C=%1.1d, S=%1.1d, E=%1.1d" %(wc,ws,we))

epsilon = 0.000005
for i in range(D):
    C  = contrast(image_stack[i])
    S  = saturation(image_stack[i])
    E  = exposedness(image_stack[i])
    Wijk[:,:,i] = (np.power(C,wc)*np.power(S,ws)*np.power(E,we)) + epsilon
normalizer = np.sum(Wijk,2)

for i in range(D):
    Wijk[:,:,i] = np.divide(Wijk[:,:,i], normalizer)
print(" *Done");print("\n")

return Wijk.astype('float64')
```

And the `lambda` function that causes error from the below function:

```
def exposedness(image, sigma=0.2):
    """
   FUNCTION: exposedness
        Call to compute third quality measure - exposure using a gaussian curve
     INPUTS:
        image = input image (colored)
        sigma = gaussian curve parameter
    OUTPUTS:
        exposedness measure
    """

    image = cv2.normalize(image, None, alpha=0.0, beta=1.0, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_64F)
    gauss_curve = lambda i : np.exp(-((i-0.5)**2) / (2*sigma*sigma))
    R_gauss_curve = gauss_curve(image[:,:,2])
    G_gauss_curve = gauss_curve(image[:,:,1])
    B_gauss_curve = gauss_curve(image[:,:,0])
    E = R_gauss_curve * G_gauss_curve * B_gauss_curve
    return E.astype('float64')
```

The error I faced:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ar\Desktop\Ab\exposure_\exposure_fusion-master\Main.py", line 36, in <module>
    weight_map      = ef.scalar_weight_map(image_stack, weights = [1,1,1])
  File "C:\Users\ar\Desktop\Ab\exposure_\exposure_fusion-master\exposureFusion_.py", line 202, in scalar_weight_map
    E  = exposedness(image_stack[i])
  File "C:\Users\ar\Desktop\Ab\exposure_\exposure_fusion-master\exposureFusion_.py", line 163, in exposedness
    R_gauss_curve = gauss_curve(image[:,:,2])
  File "C:\Users\ar\Desktop\Ab\exposure_\exposure_fusion-master\exposureFusion_.py", line 162, in <lambda>
    gauss_curve = lambda i : np.exp(-((i-0.5)**2) / (2*sigma*sigma))
  File "cupy\_core\_kernel.pyx", line 1222, in cupy._core._kernel.ufunc.__call__
  File "cupy\_core\_kernel.pyx", line 138, in cupy._core._kernel._preprocess_args
  File "cupy\_core\_kernel.pyx", line 124, in cupy._core._kernel._preprocess_arg
TypeError: Unsupported type <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

I would be grateful for any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are passing `numpy.ndarray` (data on CPU memory) to CuPy. CuPy only accepts `cupy.ndarray` (data on GPU memory), so you need to convert `image` to `cupy.ndarray` before using `gauss_curve`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I changed the type of the and solved the issue with these functions but faced another error. Because of openCV's color space conversion function cvtColor(), I think I have to edit the code for GPU programming in detail. Not sure if it will solve but I'll try edit openCV for GPU too. Error:
       `image = cv2.cvtColor(image.astype('uint8'), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'cvtColor'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - src is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
>  - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src''`

Comment: `cupy.ndarray` lives in GPU memory (where CuPy can operate on), and `numpy.ndarray` lives in CPU memory (where NumPy/OpenCV can operate on). You need to do conversion between cupy/numpy ndarray appropriately.